# Attaching data to SpatialPolygonsDataFrame

Tags: qgis, r, sp, rgdal, rgeos

As this is a more GIS related question (and maybe solvable with ogr/gdal functions I'm not aware of), I try it here first, although working with R.

What I want to achieve: I have some data, based on that data I want to create Voronoi/Thiessen polygons, but within specific geographical margins (so basically just an intersection issue). This works and is not a problem.

However, when intersecting the `SpatialPolygon` and change it to a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`, I have only the geometry, but no data attached to it. When trying to attach the data, I get an error:

> Object length mismatch:foo has 107 Polygons objects, but data has 92
>   rows

which is strange, as I used this data to create the polygons. The only thing I can come up with is that due to the intersection some polygons at the margins have been splitted in multiple parts (yet just a guess).

So here is some sample code to reproduce the problem (you can download the shp [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0AUawOi6unQTmViWkZtR2pmQUU/view?usp=sharing)). Most of the code is working, the issues arise only in the last comment section, so you may only pay attention to the last couple of lines:

```
# get data and projection
library(rgdal)
X <- c(579443.1,507821.9,527521.1,580656.9,462417.3,598714.2,528403.5,590470.2,621899.1,552101.1,579211.2,524459.0,622132.6,568279.1,551119.6,549101.4,626778.5,570531.6,498509.8,510324.2,501678.7,497111.0,566879.1,628653.7,558457.7,504368.8,482406.3,493979.3,591583.4,580834.5,579033.3,482417.6,594981.1,640817.4,583138.0,552565.4,480051.3,538693.4,595036.1,601637.4,587406.8,513506.1,511508.2,528562.7,508318.7,505132.4,560761.3,533665.2,569308.3,524761.9,538409.6,573477.6,618846.6,608033.6,601203.8,552204.2,515622.8,582403.8,493001.6,481086.7,563902.5,487437.6,626197.1,525136.5,510164.3,551818.6,486836.1,507096.5,556712.9,639675.3,553121.2,551446.2,568682.8,576450.7,490634.5,545741.7,503393.7,591073.8,561552.8,545749.3,524766.0,566276.8,578132.3,535480.5,610635.8,513964.5,520131.4,534375.5,568933.5,509446.1,475644.0,516545.3)
Y <- c(5324384,5413164,5302565,5268202,5320375,5308655,5399552,5279586,5400961,5315579,5347046,5314407,5338724,5314637,5364789,5405192,5387508,5279402,5401240,5370434,5315436,5380213,5303072,5356320,5320272,5426778,5309010,5285152,5256444,5300410,5380396,5292246,5271598,5326458,5388330,5310118,5382563,5296763,5351272,5397560,5334196,5300293,5301863,5372164,5394113,5300187,5379644,5352554,5337499,5340189,5396554,5298737,5381064,5319755,5372751,5290355,5293599,5286506,5337546,5330379,5338980,5304273,5334241,5381226,5356570,5333053,5402336,5374597,5411038,5348579,5294778,5374055,5325943,5270214,5316524,5335903,5324051,5359391,5327128,5380892,5320120,5273887,5356543,5308660,5361716,5400485,5405815,5417928,5264594,5330510,5324040,5383757)
Z <- c(339,590,924,681,495,233,568,419,214,1034,303,468,152,488,196,464,176,509,498,787,398,680,478,151,429,571,416,1492,736,811,236,495,685,145,237,524,919,751,232,183,318,1430,807,666,575,611,333,495,276,284,466,480,192,198,280,619,1076,361,486,401,244,402,149,554,904,298,539,586,451,145,601,217,855,870,634,285,338,170,583,429,469,1100,177,480,183,526,498,460,1743,263,343,595)
data <- data.frame(X,Y,Z)

data.xy <- data[c("X","Y")]
coordinates(data) <- data.xy
proj4string(data)=CRS("+init=epsg:32633")
borderorig <- readOGR('border.shp', 'border')
border <- spTransform(borderorig, CRS("+init=epsg:32633"))

# create sp voronoi/thiessen diagram 
voronoipolygons <- function(x, poly) {
  require(deldir)
  if (.hasSlot(x, 'coords')) {
    crds <- x@coords  
  } else crds <- x
  bb = bbox(poly)
  rw = as.numeric(t(bbox(poly)))
  z <- deldir(crds[,1], crds[,2],rw=rw)
  w <- tile.list(z)
  polys <- vector(mode='list', length=length(w))
  require(sp)
  for (i in seq(along=polys)) {
    pcrds <- cbind(w[[i]]$x, w[[i]]$y)
    pcrds <- rbind(pcrds, pcrds[1,])
    polys[[i]] <- Polygons(list(Polygon(pcrds)), ID=as.character(i))
  }
  SP <- SpatialPolygons(polys)

  SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(
    SP, data.frame(x=crds[,1], y=crds[,2], 
                   row.names=sapply(slot(SP, 'polygons'), 
                                    function(x) slot(x, 'ID'))))  
}

v <- voronoipolygons(data, border)
proj4string(v) <- proj4string(border)
plot(v)

# intersect and export data
###### PROBLEM STARTS HERE #######
library(rgeos)
thiessen <- gIntersection(border, v, byid=TRUE) # may take a few seconds
thiessenspdf <- as(thiessen, "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame") # change SpatialPolygon to SpatialPolygonDataFrame
notworking <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(thiessen, data@data) # not working attempt to change to spdf and attach data to polygon feature

plot(thiessenspdf)
points(data, pch=20)

writeOGR(thiessenspdf, "B:/testR", "thiessenspdf", driver="ESRI Shapefile", overwrite_layer=TRUE)
```

So what I have problems with is the `notworking <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(thiessen, data@data)` part (which is kinda self explenatory).

However, I imported the shp into QGIS and used the `Points in Polygon` function with my data points which is exactly what I want to achieve. Although there seem to be a mismatch between number of polygons and number of points (which I can't see at all on the map), it worked perfectly and I had my point data added as an attribute to each polygon - and this is how it should look like:

[image]

I need to do this in R, however, as I need to automatise this for a huge amount of different data points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is not reproducible (it depends on 'border.shp').

To make a voronoi diagram:

```
 library(dismo)
 v <- voronoi(xy)
```

To intersect while keeping attributes

```
 library(raster)
 x <- intersect(v, border)
```

After downloading the shp file:

```
library(rgdal)
library(dismo)

X <- c(579443.1,507821.9,527521.1,580656.9,462417.3,598714.2,528403.5,590470.2,621899.1,552101.1,579211.2,524459.0,622132.6,568279.1,551119.6,549101.4,626778.5,570531.6,498509.8,510324.2,501678.7,497111.0,566879.1,628653.7,558457.7,504368.8,482406.3,493979.3,591583.4,580834.5,579033.3,482417.6,594981.1,640817.4,583138.0,552565.4,480051.3,538693.4,595036.1,601637.4,587406.8,513506.1,511508.2,528562.7,508318.7,505132.4,560761.3,533665.2,569308.3,524761.9,538409.6,573477.6,618846.6,608033.6,601203.8,552204.2,515622.8,582403.8,493001.6,481086.7,563902.5,487437.6,626197.1,525136.5,510164.3,551818.6,486836.1,507096.5,556712.9,639675.3,553121.2,551446.2,568682.8,576450.7,490634.5,545741.7,503393.7,591073.8,561552.8,545749.3,524766.0,566276.8,578132.3,535480.5,610635.8,513964.5,520131.4,534375.5,568933.5,509446.1,475644.0,516545.3)
Y <- c(5324384,5413164,5302565,5268202,5320375,5308655,5399552,5279586,5400961,5315579,5347046,5314407,5338724,5314637,5364789,5405192,5387508,5279402,5401240,5370434,5315436,5380213,5303072,5356320,5320272,5426778,5309010,5285152,5256444,5300410,5380396,5292246,5271598,5326458,5388330,5310118,5382563,5296763,5351272,5397560,5334196,5300293,5301863,5372164,5394113,5300187,5379644,5352554,5337499,5340189,5396554,5298737,5381064,5319755,5372751,5290355,5293599,5286506,5337546,5330379,5338980,5304273,5334241,5381226,5356570,5333053,5402336,5374597,5411038,5348579,5294778,5374055,5325943,5270214,5316524,5335903,5324051,5359391,5327128,5380892,5320120,5273887,5356543,5308660,5361716,5400485,5405815,5417928,5264594,5330510,5324040,5383757)
Z <- c(339,590,924,681,495,233,568,419,214,1034,303,468,152,488,196,464,176,509,498,787,398,680,478,151,429,571,416,1492,736,811,236,495,685,145,237,524,919,751,232,183,318,1430,807,666,575,611,333,495,276,284,466,480,192,198,280,619,1076,361,486,401,244,402,149,554,904,298,539,586,451,145,601,217,855,870,634,285,338,170,583,429,469,1100,177,480,183,526,498,460,1743,263,343,595)
points <- data.frame(X,Y,Z)

coordinates(points) <- ~ X + Y
proj4string(points) <- CRS("+init=epsg:32633")
borderorig <- shapefile('border.shp')
border <- spTransform(borderorig, CRS("+init=epsg:32633"))

v <- voronoi(points)

thiessen <- intersect(border, v)

, byid=TRUE) # may take a few seconds
thiessenspdf <- as(thiessen, "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame") # change SpatialPolygon to SpatialPolygonDataFrame
notworking <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(thiessen, data@data) # not working attempt to change to spdf and attach data to polygon feature

plot(thiessen)
points(points, pch=20)
```

which works, but some polygons have disappeared. Because of:

```
> thiessen <- intersect(border, v)
## Warning messages:
##1: In RGEOSUnaryPredFunc(spgeom, byid, "rgeos_isvalid") :
##  Ring Self-intersection at or near point 492420.43743714999 5371917.22911005
##2: In RGEOSUnaryPredFunc(spgeom, byid, "rgeos_isvalid") :
##  Ring Self-intersection at or near point 626630.43743726006 5315517.2291098097
##3: In RGEOSUnaryPredFunc(spgeom, byid, "rgeos_isvalid") :
##  Ring Self-intersection at or near point 598680.43743717996 5400017.2291099904
##4: In RGEOSUnaryPredFunc(spgeom, byid, "rgeos_isvalid") :
##  Ring Self-intersection at or near point 543250.43743715005 5416107.22911005
```

They are easy to find by doing

```
plot(border)
```

followed by sequences of (for a particular point)

```
points(492420.43743714999, 5371917.22911005, col='red')
zoom(border)
```

[image: bad polygon]

So you may need want to clean up your polygons first

Comment: It is reproducible with the shp file you need to download...should have mentioned it earier in my initial post, sorry

Comment: Oh, yes, I overlooked that.

Comment: Cleaned up all polygons and now works perfectly with the `dismo` package. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There are places where your regions go in and out of the voronoi polygon edges, creating more features than you started with. EG in the the top:

[image]

The intersection will create some small features where the border line repeatedly crosses the straight Voronoi line.

Quite how you want to handle this depends on your application.

Comment: Oh, clearly an oversight from my side. So any idea how to just exclude those small parts with R? It seems the `Points in Polygon` function in qgis does just this by default, as it worked out there just as I wanted.